# Remove actionOverrides to managed packages

Tags: managed-package, custom-metadata, page-override

I want to set a flexipage as an org default by adding an action override to `Case.object-meta.xml`:

`<actionOverrides>
  <actionName>View</actionName>
  <content>Case_Record_Page</content>
  <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
  <type>Flexipage</type>
</actionOverrides>`

If I release this change to a managed package, does this overwrite the defaults/custom configurations of subscribers who then upgrade? Is there any way to avoid this?